# Perl truncation is Off-by-2 when outputting the line number for a string been truncated

Tags: perl, io, truncate, truncation

I am outputting the line numbers from a text file for whenever truncation occurs.  Successfully I am getting output for most truncated lines.

However, the truncated line output is off-by-2.  Here is what is happening in my code:

`Rain` , a string, is on line 1 of the input text file (see below).  Applied RegExp `s/.{4}\K.*//s` to truncate to 4 and `Rain` outputs truncated even though it was not truncated (`Rain` is 4 characters no need to shorten it).  In addition, it happens for 5, `s/.{5}\K.*//s`.

Correctly, the code outputs the truncated line when truncating by 3 or less.

How can I show NO truncation occur when using `s/.{4}\K.*//s` and `s/.{5}\K.*//s`?  In other words, when I run my code to truncate on 4 or 5, Rain displays no truncation output for the line number.

My text file - weather.txt:

```
Rain
Snow
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'weather.txt';

open my $fhIn, '<', $input or die qq(Unable to open "$input" for input: $!);

my @lines;

while( <$fhIn>) {
    chomp(@lines);
    push @lines, $. if s/.{5}\K.*//s;
}

my $max = @lines;
my $none = '-';

my $fmt = "%-20s\n";

print sprintf($fmt, "Column 1");

foreach my $i (0..$max-1) {
    print sprintf($fmt, ($lines[$i] or $none), ($lines[$i] or $none));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your text file contains a carriage return and a linefeed character at the end of each line. The `chomp` call only removes the linefeed character, leaving you with 5 characters in your lines.

A good approach is to `print` your input with some delimiters around it to inspect it:

```
print "<<$_>>\n";
```

Alternatively, you can use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to inspect your data:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper $_;
```

Personally, I really like to remove all whitespace from the end of input lines,
as keeping it is rarely wanted anyway:

```
while( <$fhIn> ) {
    s/\s+$//;
    push @lines, $. if s/.{5}\K.*//s;
};
```

Comment: It Worked.  Thanks a lot.  Will also check out the data dumper.

Comment: You can also use s/\R\z// on Perl 5.10+ to correctly remove a CRLF sequence or CR or LF alone. As a note chomp() only removes \n because on Windows the :crlf layer is applied to handles by default, which converts CRLF to \n when reading. You could apply this layer yourself if you are expecting such line endings on a non-Windows system.

Comment: Most of us are extremely relax when understanding line feeds, carriage returns, and other whitespace material.  Thanks @Grinnz for the additional information.